# How would I write a toString and reduce duplicate outputs?

Tags: java, output, tostring

So, I've created a simple app for moving a bug along a wire. The code works well (for the most part) though, I am having a few issues.

When reaching the end of the wire, the program terminates all well and good but I'm getting a double output that it's fallen off the wire when it reaches the end.

I am supposed to be writing a toString for this, but am having a bit of a hard time grasping why and how I should go about doing this.

If someone could assist with this, I'd greatly appreciate it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ClassPracticeMain {
    public static void main(String [] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int userInput;

        Bug bug1 = new Bug();
        bug1.setInitialPosition();
        bug1.setInitialDirection();
        System.out.println("Your starting position is " + bug1.initialPosition
                + " and you are facing " + bug1.getCurrentDirection()
        );
        while (bug1.getExit(1) != 0) {
            System.out.println("Which way would you like to move? 1 for left/ 2 for right or 0 for exit");
            userInput = input.nextInt();
            bug1.move(userInput);
            bug1.getCurrentDirection();
            bug1.getCurrentPosition();
            System.out.println("You are now at " + bug1.currentPosition + " and you are facing " + bug1.getCurrentDirection());
            bug1.getExit(userInput);

        }
    }
}

public class Bug {
    final int WIRELEFTEND=-15;
    final int WIRERIGHTEND=15;
    int initialPosition=0, currentPosition=0, direction,exit=1;
    String currentDirection;
    String left = "left";
    String right = "right";

    public int setInitialPosition(){
        return initialPosition;
    }

    public int setInitialDirection(){
        direction=1;
        return direction;
    }

    public int getCurrentPosition(){
        return currentPosition;
    }

    public String getCurrentDirection(){
        if (direction== 1){
            currentDirection=left;
        } else if (direction == 2){
            currentDirection=right;
        }
        return currentDirection;

    }

    public int move(int move){
        if(move==1 && direction==1){
           currentPosition=currentPosition-1;
           return currentPosition;

        } else if (move==1 && direction==2){
            direction=1;
            return currentPosition;

        } else if (move==2 && direction==1){
            direction=2;
            return currentPosition;

        } else if (move==2 && direction ==2){

            currentPosition=currentPosition+1;
            return currentPosition;
        }

        return 0;
    }

    public int getExit(int exit){
        if(currentPosition<(WIRELEFTEND)||currentPosition>WIRERIGHTEND){
            System.out.println("You've fallen off the wire... Oh no!");
            exit=0;
        } else{
            exit=exit;
        }
        return 1;
    }

}
```

Comment: Post an example of your output

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to write

```
public int getExitStatus(){
    if(currentPosition<(WIRELEFTEND)||currentPosition>WIRERIGHTEND){
        System.out.println("You've fallen off the wire... Oh no!");
        return 0;
    } 
    return 1;
}
```

instead of your current `getExist(int)` function.  It always returns 1, and setting the `exit` argument doesn't do anything.

Comment: Thank you kindly. I'll have a gander at it shortly. Hope your day has gone great!